# Passing data between components in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, components

I have implemented an image cropper in my web app like the one below

http://roadmanfong.github.io/react-cropper/example/

It's implemented as a seperate component and i'm displaying the cropped images as follows

```
<img style={{ width: '124',height:'124' }} src={this.state.cropResult} alt="cropped image"/>
```

I want to display the cropped image (which is `this.state.cropResult` ) in another image tag which is in another component. How can i share this cropped image between the components?

Comment: might need redux if they're not parent/child related

Answer (score 0):

option 1: use flux/redux

http://fluxxor.com/what-is-flux.html

http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/

option 2: Lift state up, to first component, that includes your components, which need this data

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

If the component is child of the parent component, its very easy. Just send through props.

If that component is elsewhere, you have to store data in common parent component using a callback defined parent, send to first component. first one sets data and other gets it using props.

I think redux may be a heavy investment if you just have 1 or 2 cases of transporting data.